# Numerous errors when importing web3 into app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, web3js

Attempt to import web3 into App.js gives me 9 errors

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from "web3";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TEST APP</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/galich/Desktop/projects/mp-test/node_modules/cipher-base'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

> ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/galich/Desktop/projects/mp-test/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/galich/Desktop/projects/mp-test/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib'

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Option:**

Install *NodePolyfillPlugin* and *react-app-rewired* by using `npm install react-app-rewired node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` or `yarn add react-app-rewired node-polyfill-webpack-plugin`.

Now change `"start": "react-scripts start"` to `"start": "react-app-rewired start"`.

Create a file *"config-overrides.js"* and write the following code in it:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = function override(config, _env) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new NodePolyfillPlugin({
      excludeAliases: ["console"],
    })
  );
  return config;
};
```

Now do `"npm start"` and Hurrah!!!

**2nd Option:**

Instead of importing like:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
```

Import like this:

```
import Web3 from "web3/dist/web3.min.js";
```

This will also solve your problem.